# Initializing shared memory safely

Tags: c, macos, shared-memory

I have several processes communicating with each through POSIX shared memory on OS X.
My issue is these processes could spawn in any order, and try to initialize the shared memory segment at the same time.

I tried using advisory locks with `fcntl` and `flock` but both fail telling me I'm passing an invalid file descriptor (I'm positive the file descriptor is not invalid). So clearly that's out of the picture.

Are there any alternatives to this? Or is there any details about using locks with shared memory that I'm not aware of?

Edit:
My attempt at using locks looks like this:

```
// Some declarations...

struct Queue {                                                                                          
    int index[ENTRIES_PER_QUEUE];                                                                       
    sem_t lock;                                                                                         
    sem_t readWait;                                                                                     
    sem_t writeSem;                                                                                     
    struct Entry slots[ENTRIES_PER_QUEUE];                                                              
};

struct ipc_t {
    int fd;
    char name[512];
    struct Queue* queue;
};

ipc_t ipc_create(const char* name, int owner) {

    int isInited = 1;                                                                                   
    struct Queue* queue;                                                                                
    struct flock lock = {                                                                               
        .l_type = F_WRLCK,                                                                              
        .l_whence = SEEK_SET,                                                                           
        .l_start = 0,                                                                                   
        .l_len = 0                                                                                      
    };

    ipc_t conn = malloc(sizeof(struct ipc_t));

    sprintf(conn->name, "/arqvenger_%s", name);

    conn->fd = shm_open(conn->name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
    if (conn->fd == -1) {
        free(conn);
        perror("shm_open failed");
        return NULL;
    }

    if (fcntl(conn->fd, F_SETLKW, &lock) == -1) {
        perror("Tanked...");
    }

// Do stuff with the lock & release it
```

The output I get is:

```
Tanked...: Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: @cnicutar I felt code would obscure the issue at hand, but if you feel  like it will help, it's on its way.

Comment: The code looks ok to me. I tried an isolated example and it worked.

Comment: @cnicutar was that on linux? I neglected to mention I'm using OS X. Clearly it's an important factor, on retrospect.

Comment: Okay, I've got a FreeBSD, stay put :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common technique is to first call `shm_open` with `O_CREAT|O_EXCL`. This will succeed for only one process that then has to do the setup. The others then would have to do the open as before and wait a bit, probably polling, that the setup is finished.

**Edit:** To show how this could work as discussed in the comments.

```
struct head {
 unsigned volatile flag;
 pthread_mutex_t mut;
};

void * addr = 0;
/* try shm_open with exclusive, and then */
if (/* we create the segment */) {
  addr = mmap(something);
  struct head* h = addr;
  pthread_mutex_init(&h->mut, aSharedAttr);
  pthread_mutex_lock(&h->mut);
  h->flag = 1;
  /* do the rest of the initialization, and then */
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&h->mut);
} else {
  /* retry shm_open without exclusive, and then */
  addr = mmap(something);
  struct head* h = addr;
  /* initialy flag is guaranteed to be 0 */
  /* this will break out of the loop whence the new value is written to flag */
  while (!h->flag) sched_yield();
  pthread_mutex_lock(&h->mut);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&h->mut);  
}
```

Comment: I considered doing this, and dismissed it because it either means busy waiting or using `usleep` and it doesn't sit right with me. But I guess I could fall back onto this if there's not any other way.

Comment: This sleep really only must be for a short initial time, the initialization of one flag and a mutex, e.g.

Comment: You most certainly do not need any busy waiting or sleeping. Try `shm_open(...O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL)`. If that fails, this means another process has already created your shared memory. Now try `shm_open(...O_RDWR)`. If _that_ fails, there's nothing more to try. The call will not succeed the second time around. Log a fatal error and exit. I wonder where an idea of busy-waiting could possibly be introduced into this sequence.

Comment: @n.m. There is the time between the first process has successfully created and has finished initialization. E.g you could place a `pthread_mutex_t` at the beginning of the segment. But then you'd still have to wait with another process until that mutex has been initialized. So you'd need a flag that indicates that that mutex is initialized and all other processes would have to poll that flag. With all other lock structures this is the same you have to ensure that they are initialized before you can use them. The only process that can do that is the creator, so there is a short gap.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: OK I see what you mean. On Linux 2.6 and up you can use `POSIX` semaphores to implement a named interprocess mutex (that's what `boost::interprocess::named_mutex` does if `POSIX` semaphores are available). Then you don't have to wait anywhere. If `POSIX` semaphores or some equivalent mechanism is not available, then probably busy-waiting is the only option (again, that's what `boost::interprocess::named_mutex` does). I'm not sure where OS X stands in this regard.

Comment: What you suggest doesn't seem safe to me. In case `shm_open()` succeeds to create the memory object, the object has still no size yet. You need to call `ftruncate()` on it to give it a size, prior to calling `mmap()`. If now process A succeeds to create the object using `shm_open()` but then process B runs before process A could call `ftruncate()`, process B can succeed to open the memory object and would then map the file and check for the flag being set and that will crash it with a memory access violation.

Answer (score 3):

I have been able to reproduce the problem. Then I found a sad notice in [the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html):

> When the file descriptor fildes refers to a shared memory object, the
> behavior of fcntl() shall be the same as for a regular file except the
> effect of the following values for the argument cmd shall be
> unspecified: F_SETFL, F_GETLK, F_SETLK, and **F_SETLKW**.

So it's likely it's not yet supported. For such a simple setup I would use a semaphore for signaling "the memory is ready".

#### EDIT

It seems I need to mention semaphores can be created using "O_EXCL" (so there are no races).

Comment: semaphores must be properly initialized before using them, so you have a race here.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt No I don't ? Can you point the line ? :P Seriously though, I can easily initialize semaphores with O_EXCL and no polling is necessary ;)

Comment: Ah, you are talking of named semaphores, aren't you? Using `sem_open` instead of `sem_init`? So this then would require another shared resource outside the shared segment itself, with its own naming scheme etc.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt Better than polling I think :-?

Comment: no, I don't think so. As I explained, the polling only has to be during a very brief period of initialization of one lock structure, if processes happen to jump on the same micro second (or so) for initialization. So this is a trade off situation between wasting a bit of cycles once versus wasting file descriptors and having an external data structure and convention to ensure just initialization. I'd go for the first, and if there'd be a problem, benchmarking would tell.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt Okay, so after polling, without semaphores, how would the other processes know the memory is ready ?